# Help with internet on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: wi-fi

I have just got a Samsung S3 and am having trouble getting it working on the internet properly, I've put in all the settings required from the giffgaff site and checked the network coverage link on giffgaff website and it says the area I am in has a strong signal strength. I've sent an agent on giffgaff an email to ask if my SIM has a bar on it as couldn't access the internet very good either in my iPhone just before I got this Samsung. So I know it's probably something to do with the SIM and the settings and apn all entered.

I am unsure if the phone is locked to only one network but when I brought it in the title it said it was unlocked to all networks. Can anyone else suggest anything else before I have to put in a new SIM card and have a different number?

Comment: Are you trying to connect over wi-fi or over the 3G/4G mobile network in your area? I'm not familiar with giffgaff. Is that like a pre-paid network or a contract based service?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by having a "a bar" on the SIM card? I don't fully understand your situation but I'll try to give you an answer you can work with. I've checked out Giffgaff and apparently this is a pre-paid network in the UK.

Let's forget about Internet for a second. Can you make calls with the Giffgaff SIM card in the phone? If you can, then you know your phone is not locked.

1. Get a Giffgaff SIM card.
2. Unlock your phone (if not unlocked already).
3. Activate your SIM card online.
4. Top it up.

Check out the [joining giffgaff](http://giffgaff.com/join-giffgaff) guide.

When you're done with all that you need to receive and apply the MMS and Internet settings. I believe Giffgaff will send you a special SMS message as soon as you activate your SIM card. This is a special kind of SMS that holds your Internet and MMS settings. The phone will usually prompt you to save the settings.

If you don't get this prompt you need to check the phone user manual. If you don't receive the SMS you need to re-send it from the Giffgaff website (if possible) or contact Giffgaff to have them send it to your phone number.

This covers the automatic method of setting MMS and Internet settings. This can be also done manually (recommended only for experienced users). In that case you will need to configure the APN and MMS settings.

These are the details you will need to put in the phone.

**For Internet:**

```
APN - Access Point Name: giffgaff.com
Login - Username: giffgaff
Password: password
```

**For MMS:**

```
APN - Access Point Name: giffgaff.com
Username: giffgaff
Password: password
Server - http://mmsc.mediamessaging.co.uk:8002
Port - http://mmsc.mediamessaging.co.uk:8002
MMS proxy: 193.113.200.195
MMS port: 8080
```

You can find a more complete guide [here](http://community.giffgaff.com/t5/Phone-Settings/Internet-and-MMS-settings-APN-guide/ta-p/3489121).

For settings these values in Android, you will find a guide [here](http://community.giffgaff.com/t5/Phone-Settings/Guide-Android-Phones/ta-p/3521671).

Android might ask you for details like MNC and MCC. The details above are usually enough, but here are the more complete details you will need for manually configuring MMS and Internet access on Android.

```
Access point name: giffgaff
APN: giffgaff.com
Proxy Server Address: 193.113.200.195
Proxy port / MMS port: 8080
Username: giffgaff
Password: password
MCC: 234
MNC: 10
Server / MMSC: http://mmsc.mediamessaging.co.uk:8002
APN type: mms
```

You will find a step by step instruction [here](http://community.giffgaff.com/t5/Phone-Settings/Guide-Android-Phones/ta-p/3521671). For instructions specific to your Samsung device you will need to see your user manual for the phone. You should have received a printed copy with your phone, but if you didn't receive it or have lost it you can find it online [here](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/GT-I9300MBDBTU-downloads).

For further assistance please contact Giffgaff [here](https://giffgaff.com/auth/login?redirect=/support/ask). You will need to log in with your username and password. There is also a community forum [here](http://community.giffgaff.com/t5/Help-Support/bd-p/QA1). Same thing here, to ask questions you need to log in with a username and password.

You're probably better off presenting your problem to the Giffgaff community than asking here at Android SE, as these are Giffgaff users who probably better understand how this network works and what the requirements are than any average user here at Android SE would know.

If you still need Samsung specific instructions for setting up Internet and MMS, drop a comment here below. Good luck!